# Detect if the last three characters of inventory_hostname is odd or even

Tags: ansible

I have a use case where I need to assign a different server based on the hostname in an Ansible playbook, if it is odd or even. For example, if the server is odd:

```
host: myhost-001.example.com server: myserver-003.example.com
```

If it is not odd, then it has to be even, so I would assign a different server:

```
host: myhost-002.example.com server: myserver-002.example.com
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting issue. You can do this using jinja filters:

```
{{ 'myhost-002.example.com'|regex_replace('(myhost-)(?P<id>\d\d\d)(\.example\.com)', '\\g<id>')|int is divisibleby 2 }}
```

Let's break down this to explain a bit:

```
'myhost-002.example.com'
```

First I assume that a host variable is in the form above.

```
|regex_replace('(myhost-)(?P<id>\d\d\d)(\.example\.com)', '\\g<id>')
```

I do a regex replace with named parameters, keeping only the `id` parameter which in the above example I assume to be three numbers `\d\d\d`. This should return `'002'`.

```
|int is divisibleby 2
```

Then I check that the above integer is divisible by 2 to determine if odd or even.

Test:

```
ansible localhost -m debug -a "msg={{ 'myhost-002.example.com'|regex_replace('(myhost-)(?P<id>\d\d\d)(\.example\.com)', '\\g<id>')|int is divisibleby 2 }}"

localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "msg": true
}
```

Useful links: [Ansible Jinja2 filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#other-useful-filters)